# How can I change the color of my body when using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying out programming Bootstrap and when I was going to change the color of my `body` using simply:

```
body {
  background-color: #eba; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
```

It didn't work, so my question is how can I style anything when using Bootstrap? I've looked in the developer's tools and found that `background-color: #eba;` got ignored and replaced by the default Bootstrap `body color`, why is that? Shouldn't the Bootstrap Default `body color` get ignored instead of mine? 
(I might have put two questions in one, so forgive me).

**Relevant HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <h4>Column 1</h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro exercitationem provident explicabo ipsa consequuntur, quidem dolorem perferendis veritatis facilis fugiat deleniti natus quod laboriosam eum incidunt consequatur cumque voluptates. Repellat.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <h4>Column 2</h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro exercitationem provident explicabo ipsa consequuntur, quidem dolorem perferendis veritatis facilis fugiat deleniti natus quod laboriosam eum incidunt consequatur cumque voluptates. Repellat.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <h4>Column 3</h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro exercitationem provident explicabo ipsa consequuntur, quidem dolorem perferendis veritatis facilis fugiat deleniti natus quod laboriosam eum incidunt consequatur cumque voluptates. Repellat.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <h4>Column 4</h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro exercitationem provident explicabo ipsa consequuntur, quidem dolorem perferendis veritatis facilis fugiat deleniti natus quod laboriosam eum incidunt consequatur cumque voluptates. Repellat.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #eba;
}
```

Comment: are you including your css after bootstrap.css? if yes then change order and include your css after including all.

Comment: @Alorika use of '!important' is not a solution.. the give CSS is correct..please put your CSS below bootstrap CSS

Comment: you might be including bootstrap.min.css file after the styling mentioned above which result in overriding your css by bootstrap css

Comment: @PrajwalShrestha, Will disagree with you..The `!important` rule overrides that particular property. Simple and effective solution..

Comment: @RayonDabre We will not use '!important' in CSS, when we use such a important in our CSS, the Standard will loss..so we do not use important as much as possible.

Comment: @PrajwalShrestha, Are you kidding me ?

Comment: @RayonDabre No Why am I? You can ignore my points if you don't satisfied..

Comment: Then why do we have `!important` ? What _standards_ will be lost ? It is not about satisfaction! You provide convincing content that's it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

place your custom css after including bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css

or add !important keyword to your css

```
<style type="text/css">
body{background: #eba !important;}
</style>
```

Comment: !important is used when you want to execute this style whether another declarations are also exists.

Comment: Thanks, I was using the `CDN` before, now I'm using the min.css file, it works nicely now, :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to include your custom `.css` file after `bootstrap.css/bootstrap.min.css`
Or else you can use `'!important'` to make your change.

For example :

```
body {
  background-color: #eba !important; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
```